# average attention time and attention compensation time

Tags: cognitive-psychology, educational-psychology, attention

Is there any good source for statistics regarding average attention span? More specifically- what is the average attention compensation time, meaning- how long does a person need to rest in order to fully restore his/her attention?

Comment: That's not a self-help question.

Comment: This varies depending on environment and stimuli. Could you be more specific about what circumstances you would want this statistic to be studied under?